# Semiprimitivity of second dual of semiprime Banach algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra. Then $A^*$ is right Banach $A$-module with product $\langle b,f.a\rangle=\langle ab,f\rangle$ for every $a,b\in A, f\in A^*$. Define 
$\langle a,F*f\rangle=\langle f.a,F\rangle$ for every $a\in A,f\in A^*, F\in A^{**}$, and define $\langle f,F\square G\rangle=\langle G*f,F\rangle$, for all $F,G\in A^{**}, f\in A^{*}$. the product $\square$ on $A^{**}$ is called ***first Arens product*** and it makes $A^{**}$ into a Banach algebra.

Also we say that the Banach algebra $A$ is semi-prime if for all ideals $I$ of $A$, the $I^2=\{0\}$ implies $I=\{0\}$.

**Question1:** Under which conditions, $A$ is a left or right or bi-ideal of $(A^{**},\square)$?

**Question2:** If $A$ is semi-prime Banach algebra, could we say that $A^{**}$ is semiprime? If not, under which conditions we could say it?